# How to remove 'Aa' from the legend in Plotly.py?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

How to remove 'Aa' from the legend?

The code below is from the example on this page under *Adding Text to Data in Line and Scatter Plots*: https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[1, 1, 1],
    mode="lines+markers+text",
    name="Lines, Markers and Text",
    text=["Text A", "Text B", "Text C"],
    textposition="top center"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[2, 2, 2],
    mode="markers+text",
    name="Markers and Text",
    text=["Text D", "Text E", "Text F"],
    textposition="bottom center"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[3, 3, 3],
    mode="lines+text",
    name="Lines and Text",
    text=["Text G", "Text H", "Text I"],
    textposition="bottom center"
))

fig.show()
```

> Edit:
> I would like to keep the text in the markers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

#### Advanced Solution

The advanced solution is to customize the CSS before calling `fig.show()`:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("""
<style>
g.pointtext {display: none;}
</style>
""")

fig.show()
```

This results in the desired behavior.

#### Simple solution

The 'Aa' is the result of the existence of text in the markers. If you remove text and leave just markers and lines, the 'Aa' disappears.

For example:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[1, 1, 1],

    # mode="lines+markers+text",  # comment out
    mode="lines+markers",         # new code 

    name="Lines, Markers and Text",
    text=["Text A", "Text B", "Text C"],
    textposition="top center"
))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there a way to remove 'Aa' while still keeping the text in the markers?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the current latest plotly cdn

```
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

'Aa' will disappear